# Taking the derivative of an integral from $x$ to $1$

Tags: calculus, integration

When applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, how do you find the derivative of an integral from $x$ to $1$?

For example, take the integral
$$\int_{x}^{1}h^3\cdot f(h)\, dh\tag{1}$$
where the limits of integration are from $x$ to $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $\int_x^1 f(t)~dt=-\int_1^xf(t)~dt$

Comment: Thank you!! Very helpful–after this, would I just plug in x for t? so it would just become x^3 f(x)?

Comment: @gticecream8 Sounds about right, make sure you have the $-$